# Can i use min-width and max-width in a stylesheet

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm making my website more mobile friendly, I have successful made it good for phones but trying to use both min and max-width stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 1050px)" href="./css/max-1050px.css">
```

I want to put `media="(min-width: 501px, max-width: 1050px)`.
Am I doing it right?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_media.asp see the link, you can use it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use logical operators.  The correct syntax is

```
media="(min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 1050px)"
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
100vm //100 means width of window, 1 means 1/100 of window
100vh // same for height
100vmin //100%  of whichever is smaller, width of height
100vmax //100% of whichever is larger
```